# Stop ExtJS grid from scrolling on refresh

Tags: scroll, datagrid, extjs6-classic

I have a grid in ExtJS 6.0.2 that can be set to auto-refresh (it reloads once every ~10 seconds), but when it does, I want it to stay where it is instead of scrolling to the top each time. We have successfully used `preserveScrollOnRefresh` to do this with other grids, but for one particular grid, it's not working. In order to try to get it working, I decided to try calling `getScrollY()` before reloading the store and `setScrollY()` after, but that didn't work either. When I stepped through with the debugger, for some reason, `getScrollY()` returned 0 even when I had the grid scrolled all the way to the bottom.

Is there anything else that I can try?

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like this is working for other grids in your app, so without seeing any code I'd suggest that something with that store/grid ecosystem is not configured the same as other grids in your app.

perhaps post a fiddle (fiddle.sencha.com) with an example, that may also help you find your answer if the fiddle works.